# Is there any way is ther to create a ".O" file without main() function in ".C" file 

Tags: c++, windows, linux, g++, cc

In linux : C++

Is there any way is ther to create a ".O" file without main() function in ".C" file .

iam using

```
     "cc -c file.c -o file.o  " with sun compiler  
     " gcc -Wall -c file.c " with g++ compiler
```

may i know

1) what command we need to use for with EDG compiler  and any other C++ compielrs in LINUX

2) In windows may i know for any compilers ..even g++,cc,intel,etc ...?

please ...

i have seen this question ?

[Possible to compile any .c file in isolation (that is, without a main?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200595/possible-to-compile-any-c-file-in-isolation-that-is-without-a-main)

but i didn't find the answer ...

Comment: There are a lot of compilers out there. Which ones are you actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost any compiler, `-c`should produce a `.o` file by default. You can use the same syntax as with your sun compiler : `-o` is supported as well by gcc.

This should work just fine:

```
 gcc -Wall -c file.c -o file.o
```

Note that on windows, `.o`files are usually named `.obj` as a visual convention : it might be a good idea to stick to that convention.

I think that if suing visual studio compiler in command line, you must use `/c` to make it compile, as defined on [MS web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx)

Last, if you're compiling C++, you should use g++ instead of gcc afaik.

Answer (score 1):

gcc -c file.c should work just fine?

Answer (score 1):

Every C compiler I am aware of recognizes the `-c` flag for this mode of compilation.